# How to get the redirected page URL Httpclient

Tags: android

The below code helps me to login to a page and gets me all Html content of redirected page.But, when I get the url it gives me the old login url.

How do I get the redirected page URL?

```
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(UrlLink);
    try {
        // Add user name and password

        String username = "xxxxxxx";
        String password = "yyyyyyy";
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("login", username));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        Log.v("SENCIDE", "Execute HTTP Post Request");
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        InputStream is=response.getEntity().getContent();
old --->String newUrl=httppost.getURI().toString();
Url                 Log.v("ddd",newUrl);
        String line = "";
         StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
         BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

         try {
          while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) { 
            total.append(line); 
          }
          Log.v("dfd",total.toString());
         } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
         }
```

[image]

Comment: look at the response's `Location` header

Comment: Not able to understand can u elaborate plz..

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/RedirectHandler.html

Comment: should be something like the following `String redirectURL = response.getFirstHeader("Location").getValue();` let me know so I can post it as the answer.

Comment: If I insert that line it throws error msg

Comment: Plz See up in the code I have posted the logcat output after copying the line String redirectURL = response.getFirstHeader("Location").getValue();